# Catching a SQL Server stored procedure that is exiting unexpectedly

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure that seems to be exiting unexpectedly. I have try catch inside the stored procedure but that code is never hit. Running the stored procedure (`spInner`) manually from SQL Server Management Studio results in it working as expected. When the stored procedure (`spInner`) is called from my application it is called from inside another stored procedure (`spOuter`). I am not doing that when I do my manual testing but it shouldn't effect the outcome and shouldn't effect the logging.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInner]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @NeedsRefresh BIT;
    SET @NeedsRefresh = 0;

    BEGIN TRY  
        INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
        VALUES ('Begin', SYSDATETIME());

        CREATE TABLE #TestPCWorking(...)

        INSERT INTO #TestPCWorking 
            SELECT * FROM ...;

        CREATE TABLE #ActivePCsWorking(...)

        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TestPCWorking)
        BEGIN
            SET @NeedsRefresh = 1;

            INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
            VALUES ('Before adhoc update', SYSDATETIME());

            UPDATE ...

            -- This statement executes
            INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
            VALUES ('After adhoc update', SYSDATETIME());

            -- This statement executes
            INSERT INTO #ActivePCsWorking
                SELECT ...;  -- This is a big query selecting from #TestPCWorking

            -- This statement executes
            INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
            VALUES ('After first #ActivePCsWorking insert', SYSDATETIME());

            INSERT INTO #ActivePCsWorking
                SELECT ...;  -- This is a different big query selecting from #TestPCWorking;

            -- I never get this message
            INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
            VALUES ('After second #ActivePCsWorking insert', SYSDATETIME());
        END

        INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
        VALUES ('Checking @NeedsRefresh', SYSDATETIME());

        IF (@NeedsRefresh = 1)
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            INSERT INTO RealTable 
                SELECT FROM #ActivePCsWorking;

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
            VALUES ('Never arrives', SYSDATETIME());
        END

        DROP TABLE #ActivePCsWorking;
        DROP TABLE #TestPCWorking;
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- This message is never added
        INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
        VALUES ('Before rollback error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), SYSDATETIME());

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
        VALUES ('Encountered an error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), SYSDATETIME());

        -- Save the error info
        EXECUTE spGetErrorInfo; -- This logs the error but nothing is logged
    END CATCH;   
END
```

This stored procedure is called from another stored procedure. I also have a catch there:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spOuter]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC spInner;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO ServerErrors (ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime) 
        VALUES ('Encountered an error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), SYSDATETIME());

        -- Save the error info
        EXECUTE spGetErrorInfo;  
    END CATCH    
END
```

I can see my "log" entries up until "After first #ActivePCsWorking insert". The code just exits at that point. No errors are written to the error log, the extra "servererror" logs are never written. There isn't an exception thrown in the calling application. It's like the stored procedure has a return statement in place of the second insert.

Is there any way that I can figure out what is causing the stored procedure to exit? One of the links I read indicated that wrapping the call to the stored procedure in another call would catch any additional errors that normally fall through but I am not seeing any of those either.

Comment: Considering you have `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TestPCWorking)` afterwards and you say nothing else happens after the statement **prior** to that, I'd suggest that `EXISTS` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: In a catch statement, if you want to write to the database, you have to check whether an uncommitable  transaction exists, and if so roll it back. Otherwise you are unable to do anything to affect data in the database. So first line of the catch block should be `if xact_state() != 0 rollback;` After that you can insert into the database again.

Comment: @DaleBurrell - Your comment made me look at a few things again. In this case, the command was timing out after 30 seconds. For some reason, that wasn't triggering an exception on the client. I will dig into that later. For now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem was that the command was timing out. The second insert statement was taking approximately 35 seconds and the command timeout was set to 30 seconds. SQL server just kills the stored proc when the timeout occurs.